# Potato with purple veins!

Tags: botany, vegetable

Today while cooking with potatoes when I cut open a potato(raw) which was looking perfect from the outside showed purple veins. I threw it in my kitchen garden but than I wondered what it could be

[image: My weird potatoes]

**Questions**

1. Why did my potato developed these purple patterns?
2. What could be that purple pigment?
3. Are such potatoes Edible?

PS: The potato was not old. It was quite fresh.

Answer (score 3):

The potato developed this pattern because it's (probably) natural to cultivar you're growing or due to cross-pollination.
Purple pigment is [anthocyanin](http://www.sciepub.com/reference/136930). It's perfectly normal and considered as more healthy (as those varieties of potatoes contain more antioxidants and vitamin C) and even ['gourmet'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitelotte).